# Crossword Puzzles: What is this crossword type?

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, crosswords

I found these rules for a crossword, but I don't know what type it is. Can anyone help me?

The rules:

> - The words are given and you're asked to place them on the grid!
> - The grid and the list of words are provided separately and are not numbered.
> - The goal is to place all the words on the grid so that all the crossings of words are valid.
> - Usually a word is placed on the grid as a starting point for the solver.

Here is a [link](http://www.stayrolexakias.gr/amerikaniko) of this type of crossword from a Greek site.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "definitions indicate the position of the words within the grid." In the example you link, there are no definitions, just a list of words to be placed in the grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a **fill-in**, **fill-it-in**, or **word fill** puzzle, depending on who is publishing it.

A crossword grid is given, along with a list of words. The task is to fill in the grid with the given words (across and down) so that the grid is filled, and all words are used.

There is a [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fill-In_(puzzle)) about it.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for, but it looked not very famous :(

Comment: @bilisios Does my first "Crossword Day puzzle" fit?

Answer (score 7):

I believe the term you're looking for is *diagramless crossword*. [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossword#Major_crossword_variants):

> In a diagramless crossword, often called a diagramless for short or, in the UK, a skeleton crossword or carte blanche, the grid offers overall dimensions, but the locations of most of the clue numbers and shaded squares are unspecified. A solver must deduce not only the answers to individual clues, but how to fit together partially built-up clumps of answers into larger clumps with properly-set shaded squares.

Comment: Now that a freely accessible link has been posted, it's become clear that this is not the right answer.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a *criss-cross* - here's a description from the MIT Mystery Hunt puzzle archive.

http://devjoe.appspot.com/huntindex/keyword/crisscross

> In its standard form, this puzzle consists of a loosely interlocking grid and a list of words to be filled in. You must use logic and elimination to figure out where to place the words. This category includes puzzles where the word list is clued rather than provided, but if the clues are associated with specific entries, this becomes a crossword puzzle instead.

Comment: Hmm, I think this is actually it (the OP's link seems to require an email and password, so I can't tell...), but I'm not sure I understand the description in the question entirely. Does "the grid [... is] provided" mean just the dimensions, or the whole outline? (I've upvoted your answer, but I'll keep mine as well so that the OP can clarify.)

Comment: @Doorknob: I tried to make some sense of the post but couldn't quite figure out everything - it's possible that some of my interpretations could be wrong.